# script to find similar email users

Tags: bash, email

We have a mail server and I am trying to write a script that will find all users with similar names to avoid malicious users from impersonating legitimate users. For example, a legit user may have the name of `james2014@domain.com` but a malicious user may register as `james20l4@domain.com`. The difference, if you notice carefully, is that I replaced the number 'one' with the letter 'l' (el). So I am trying to write something that can consult my `/var/vmail/domain/*` and find similar names and alert me (the administrator). I will then take the necessary steps to do what I need. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you post the code that you already have?

Comment: Expanding on what Sean said: we don't write code for you here on StackOverflow.  If you have specific question, with actual code and complete error messages, we can help you understand why things are failing, but you first need to demonstrate that you've done your own research and tried to solve the problem.

Comment: I doubt you would be able to come up with anything sufficient generic using bash.  I would put all of the e-mail addresses into a ternary search tree or similar data structure and then use a proximity search to find potentially illegitimate addresses.

Comment: Rather than a script, perhaps is there a command in bash to group similar file names, possibly the find command? I can run the command manually and scan over the directories with `ls -ld a*` to view all users beginning with 'a' for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hacky way to do this is to derive "normalized" versions of your usernames, put those in an associative array as keys mapping to the original input, and use those to find problems.

The example I posted below uses [bash associative arrays](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html) to store the mapping from normalized name to original name, and [`tr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) to switch some characters for other characters (and delete other characters entirely).

I'm assuming that your list of users will fit into memory; you'll also need to tweak the mapping of modified and removed characters to hit your favorite balance between effectiveness and false positives. If your list can't fit in memory, you can use a single file or the filesystem to approximate it, but honestly if you're processing that many names you're probably better off with a non-shell programming language.

**Input:**

```
doc
dopey
james2014
happy
bashful
grumpy
james20l4
sleepy
james.2014
sneezy
```

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# stdin: A list of usernames. stdout: Pairs of names that match.
CHARS_TO_REMOVE="._\\- "
CHARS_TO_MAP_FROM="OISZql"
CHARS_TO_MAP_TO="0152g1"

normalize() {
  # stdin: A word. stdout: A modified version of the same word.
  exec tr "$CHARS_TO_MAP_FROM" "$CHARS_TO_MAP_TO" \
      | tr --delete "$CHARS_TO_REMOVE" \
      | tr "A-Z" "a-z"
}

declare -A NORMALIZED_NAMES
while read NAME; do
  NORMALIZED_NAME=$(normalize <<< "$NAME")
  # -n tests for non-empty strings, as it would be if the name were set already.
  if [[ -n ${NORMALIZED_NAMES[$NORMALIZED_NAME]} ]]; then
    # This name has been seen before! Print both of them.
    echo "${NORMALIZED_NAMES[$NORMALIZED_NAME]} $NAME"
  else
    # This name has not been seen before. Store it.
    NORMALIZED_NAMES["$NORMALIZED_NAME"]="$NAME"
  fi
done
```

**Output:**

```
james2014 james20l4
james2014 james.2014
```

Comment: This is definitely alot better than manually listing the users per first letter and trying to find similar names. I can always play around with the characters to map from but I think you included most of the ones that look similar. Thanks!